# How can I add a check box for optional files during install in Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I'm trying to make a custom checkbox in my custom page (because it's a one page installer), is needed only a checkbox without dialogs or anything, the installer that I'm trying to compile is very linear and simple.

I want to bind `FILE3.EXE` on a checkbox in this way: if checkbox is checked copy the file (`FILE3.EXE`) in `DestDir`, otherwise if checkbox is unchecked skip the file (`FILE3.EXE`) during installation.

This is the code that I used, obviously the checkbox code is missing because I'm not able to do that

```
[Files]
Source: FILE1.EXE; DestDir: {app};
Source: FILE2.EXE; DestDir: {app};
Source: FILE3.EXE; DestDir: {app}; //OPTIONAL
```

```pascal
[Code]
procedure ExitProcess(uExitCode: UINT);
external 'ExitProcess@kernel32.dll stdcall';

var
  MainPage : TWizardPage;
  FolderToInstall : TEdit;
  InstallLocation : String;

procedure CancelClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if ExitSetupMsgBox then
  begin
    ExitProcess(0);
  end;
end;

procedure BrowseClick(Sender : TObject);
var
  Dir : String;

begin
  Dir := FolderToInstall.Text;
  if BrowseForFolder('Browse',Dir,false) then
    FolderToInstall.Text := Dir;
  WizardForm.DirEdit.Text := Dir;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard();
var
  LabelFolder : TLabel;
begin
  MainPage := CreateCustomPage(wpWelcome,'','');
  LabelFolder := TLabel.Create(MainPage);
  LabelFolder.Parent := WizardForm;
  LabelFolder.Top := 164;
  LabelFolder.Left := 6;
  LabelFolder.Caption := 'Directory:'

  FolderToInstall := TEdit.Create(MainPage);
  FolderToInstall.Parent := WizardForm;
  FolderToInstall.Top := 182;
  FolderToInstall.Left := 85;
  FolderToInstall.Width := 380;
  FolderToInstall.Text :=  WizardDirValue;
  FolderToInstall.ReadOnly := True;
end;
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to make a [`Check`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptcheck.htm#Check) function which will return state of the check box from the [`[Code]`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptcreating.htm) section of your script. Something like this might do what you want, but before the code script I would correct you in the following:

- use ***TNew...*** classes where you're able to, so in your case use [`TNewEdit`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptclasses.htm#TNewEdit) instead of [`TEdit`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptclasses.htm#TEdit)
- use [`TWizardPage.Surface`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptclasses.htm#TWizardPage) as a `Parent` if you want to have a certain component on the page (here I'm not sure if that's your intention, just pointing this out :-)
- format your code, it doesn't need to be so flat

In the following example I've used [`Check`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptcheck.htm#Check) function called `InstallHelpFile` for conditional install of a certain file, in this case `MyProg.chm`. The [`Check`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptcheck.htm#Check) function works simply; when you return True to the function, the file is processed, skipped is when you return False.

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program
OutputDir=userdocs:Inno Setup Examples Output

[Files]
Source: "MyProg.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "MyProg.chm"; DestDir: "{app}"; Check: InstallHelpFile;
```

```pascal
[Code]
var
  InstallHelpCheckBox: TNewCheckBox;  

procedure InitializeWizard;
var  
  LabelFolder: TLabel;  
  MainPage: TWizardPage;  
  FolderToInstall: TNewEdit;  
begin
  MainPage := CreateCustomPage(wpWelcome, '', '');
  LabelFolder := TLabel.Create(MainPage);
  LabelFolder.Parent := WizardForm;
  LabelFolder.Top := 164;
  LabelFolder.Left := 6;
  LabelFolder.Caption := 'Directory:'

  FolderToInstall := TNewEdit.Create(MainPage);
  FolderToInstall.Parent := MainPage.Surface;
  FolderToInstall.Top := 182;
  FolderToInstall.Left := 85;
  FolderToInstall.Width := 380;
  FolderToInstall.Text :=  WizardDirValue;
  FolderToInstall.ReadOnly := True;

  InstallHelpCheckBox := TNewCheckBox.Create(MainPage);
  InstallHelpCheckBox.Parent := MainPage.Surface;
  InstallHelpCheckBox.Top := FolderToInstall.Top + FolderToInstall.Height + 8;
  InstallHelpCheckBox.Left := FolderToInstall.Left;
  InstallHelpCheckBox.Width := FolderToInstall.Width;
  InstallHelpCheckBox.Caption := 'Install help file';
end;

function InstallHelpFile: Boolean;
begin
  { here is the Check function used above; if you return True to this }
  { function, the file will be installed, when False, the file won't }
  { be installed }
  Result := InstallHelpCheckBox.Checked;
end;
```

Answer (score 33):

You don't have to manually create checkboxes for that. The standard way to let the user choose what to install is to use the `[Types]` and `[Components]` sections of your script file.

Take a look at the `Components.iss` script located in your Inno Setup install folder\examples.

```
; -- Components.iss --
; Demonstrates a components-based installation.

; SEE THE DOCUMENTATION FOR DETAILS ON CREATING .ISS SCRIPT FILES!

[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program
DefaultGroupName=My Program
UninstallDisplayIcon={app}\MyProg.exe
OutputDir=userdocs:Inno Setup Examples Output

[Types]
Name: "full"; Description: "Full installation"
Name: "compact"; Description: "Compact installation"
Name: "custom"; Description: "Custom installation"; Flags: iscustom

[Components]
Name: "program"; Description: "Program Files"; Types: full compact custom; Flags: fixed
Name: "help"; Description: "Help File"; Types: full
Name: "readme"; Description: "Readme File"; Types: full
Name: "readme\en"; Description: "English"; Flags: exclusive
Name: "readme\de"; Description: "German"; Flags: exclusive

[Files]
Source: "MyProg.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Components: program
Source: "MyProg.chm"; DestDir: "{app}"; Components: help
Source: "Readme.txt"; DestDir: "{app}"; Components: readme\en; Flags: isreadme
Source: "Readme-German.txt"; DestName: "Liesmich.txt"; DestDir: "{app}"; Components: readme\de; Flags: isreadme

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\My Program"; Filename: "{app}\MyProg.exe"
```

At runtime, the installer presents this dialog within the wizard:

[image: Components dialog]

Answer (score 4):

You can do it much easier with CreateInputOptionPage(). See detailed information in Inno Setup help. http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptpages

Answer (score 1):

```
// Create:
for i := 0 to g_SetupX_Count do begin
    WizardForm.ComponentsList.AddCheckBox(g_SetupX_Name[i], '', 0, g_SetupX_Active[i], true, false, false, nil);
    g_SetupX_CompListIndex[i] := nextPosi;
    nextPosi := nextPosi + 1;
end;

// Evaluate:
for i := 0 to g_SetupX_Count do begin
    g_SetupX_Active[i] := WizardForm.ComponentsList.Checked[g_SetupX_CompListIndex[i]];
end;
```