# Disable setup types dropdown list on Inno Setup Selected Components page

Tags: inno-setup

Is it possible to disable the dropdown menu that appears on the *Select Components* page of the installer? Will this negatively affect anything or can the user be fine with just checking the components he/she wants manually?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just specify a single custom setup type (`iscustom` flag) and you will get the *Select Components* screen without the dropdown menu.

```
[Types]
Name: "custom"; Description: "Custom installation"; Flags: iscustom
```

And include all components into the `custom` type:

```
[Components]
Name: "program"; Description: "Program Files"; Types: custom; Flags: fixed
Name: "help"; Description: "Help File"; Types: custom;
...
```

[image: Select Components screen]

Comment: The same example with more details about the **optional choice** (radio buttons for the help language) you find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13502485/789423).